# Programmatically disable the permission "this input method may be able to collect all the text you type ." in customed android soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I am developing a custom keyboard.I am following this Link to make this Keyboard

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

As a beginner in android developing ,I have changed some design and add color in this keyboard.But when i try this in my android device and enable this keyboard , it takes appear a ATTENTION

This input method may be able to collect all the text that you type, including personal data like passwords and credit card numbers. ....

As i am not taking any data from user , i want to disable this.I have disable all the permission in AndroidManifest.xml file .but it is not works,
how can i disable this in programmatically and disable this permission ?

Comment: The warning is there not because you are doing it, but because you could.  Any keyboard could-  just dump all the text typed to a file.  As such, the OS warns you about turning on a highly dangerous application.  This is a good thing for the user and should not be removed (and can't be, short of a custom OS).

Comment: Thanks but many android keyboard i found that does not show this warning or Attention, is there any way to disable this warning, it seems dangerous for the user who used my developed keyboard -@Gabe Sechan

Comment: Every keyboard has this warning when you set it as the default IME, with the possible exception of pre-installed keyboards.  There is no way to disable this warning, and there should be no way to disable it.

Comment: Tnx a lot for your kind reply .Sir  would u plz tell me abot SwiftKey Keyboard.when i install this the below link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey.it does not  show any warning , how they managed this ?- Gabe Sechan

Answer (score 5):

Fortunately, that is not possible. Otherwise, malware authors would simply disable this warning.

Comment: how can i disable this warning , it seems dangerous for the user who used my developed keyboard -CommonsWare

Comment: @buddhobaniksagor: "how can i disable this warning" -- you can't. "it seems dangerous for the user who used my developed keyboard" -- then do not distribute the keyboard to users. This message is not unique to your app. It will appear for any keyboard app that the user installs and attempts to enable.

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your useful reply  but many android keyboard i found and install in my mobile that does not show this warning or Attention, then how can they do or they hide this warning . Is there any way to do this ? - CommonsWare

Comment: @buddhobaniksagor: Perhaps the issue is with your device. The device manufacturer can disable this warning for any keyboards that they pre-install, and perhaps they have marketing deals with some of those others that you test.

Comment: Apple actually gives the developer the option not to request Full Access. But yeah, not an option on Android.